# prevent unknown css properties from being removed from the style attribute

Tags: html, css

So basically I have some js that adds a style attribute with some css filters. I have added both a webkit-prefixed and an unprefixed version of the property, like this:

```
<img src="image.jpg" style="filter: blur(10px); -webkit-filter: blur(10px)"/>
```

I need to save that html and display it in a different browser. However, the filters aren't visible in different browsers, because the unknown attributes are removed. For example, if the filters were added in webkit, the non-prefixed property is removed by the browser, preventing the html from later working in firefox. What I would like is a way to override the browser's removing unknown properties from the style attribute, so that the unprefixed version is visible in a different browser. I know I can add some js that recalculates the filters on pageload, but I would prefer not to do this. Is there a better solution?

Comment: What is your way of getting the html?

Comment: $("my-element").html() (I use jquery). Later, html is added in a different browser using $("my-element").html(the-html)

Comment: I don’t think you can get browsers to keep those “unknown” styles. What you are getting with `.html()` is not the original HTML code – but a serialized representation of the DOM the browser constructed from it, so those properties are effectively “lost” at that point. You could put them into a custom data attribute to begin with (in the HTML code), the content of that will stay “as is” (because it is treated as pure text) – so that you could read them from there and transfer them over to the `style` attribute later on.

Comment: It is entirely unclear to me what you are actually trying to accomplish with this, but this seems like a round-about and hackish way to get anything done. How is javascript from one browser going to save the HTML in a place that javascript in a different browser can use it? Maybe if you explain the actual goal (where this question is the proposed solution to the goal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have your example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kguz1dep/) and you can see (e.g. in Chrome) that the style attribute is not even updated with the css attributes that don't apply and

```
$().html()
```

will get those only.

In your problem it may be that you don't really need the prefixes.

Worth to notice is this fact, taken from jQuery decumentation, that

> As of jQuery 1.8, the .css() setter will automatically take care of prefixing the property name.

So you don't need to add all of them, jQuery 1.8+ will take care of it.

Following the topic of retrieving html with dynamically added style - you can retrieve it with .html() if you first add this with .attr('style', 'filter: -webkit-filter: blur(10px)');